# Prevent user from typing more than a single decimal, and prevent user from typing more than 2 numbers after decimal

Tags: javascript

I've currently got this JS code attached that validates for numbers and dots in an input, but I want to also prevent user from typing in more than one dot for decimal, and not more than two other numbers after the dot.

How can I do this?

Thank you

```js
function validate(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    // Handle paste
    if (theEvent.type === 'paste') {
        key = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    } else {
    // Handle key press
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    }
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
      theEvent.returnValue = false;
      if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

```html
        <input placeholder="Enter amount..." maxlength="5" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var inputField = theEvent.target || theEvent.srcElement;

  // prevent user pasting in values
  if (theEvent.type === 'paste') {
    key = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  } else {
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  }

  // allow only numbers and dots
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  // check if there is already a dot
  if (key === '.' && inputField.value.includes('.')) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  // only 2 numbers after dot
  var parts = inputField.value.split('.');
  if (parts.length === 2 && parts[1].length >= 2 && key !== '.') {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter amount..." maxlength="5" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
```

Comment: Bro This is not working ??

Comment: @YasserCHENIK It was accepted because it resolved the OP's issue, and is therefore clearly working. Out of curiosity, what browser are you using - I've had issues with *input* behaviour varying based on browser.

Comment: I m using brave , and it's not working .